# What is the antonym of "abjure"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

1. Affirm
2. Cajole
3. Insist
4. Pronounce
5. Shout

What's your opinion?

Comment: Conjure could be, with some semantic magic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look up 
[abjure](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3aabjure) in a dictionary, you will find:

> formally reject or disavow a formerly held belief

The two most likely antonyms are *insist* and *affirm*. But [affirm](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=define%3aaffirm&btnG=Search)'s is closer:

> confirm: establish or strengthen as with new evidence or facts

Answer (score 4):

The opposite of ***abjure*** is ***objure***.  Per the [OED](http://oed.com/view/Entry/129654):

> Etymology: classical Latin *obiūrāre* to bind by an oath < [*ob*- prefix](http://oed.com/view/Entry/129506) + *iūrāre* to swear (see [jurant](http://oed.com/view/Entry/102130) *adj*. and *n*.). Compare Middle French objurer (1460 as *oubjurer*).
>
> 1. *trans*. To bind by or charge under oath; to urge.
>
>    - 1609 R. Cawdrey *Table Alph*., ― *Obiure*, binde by oath.
>    - 1993 Irish Times (Nexis) 9 Feb. 17 — We are objured, in our so-called freedom of monetary exchange, to be patriotic.
> 2. *intr*. To utter an oath, to curse. *Obs*.
>
>    - 1830 *Fraser’s Mag.* II. 178 ― As the people only laughed at him, he cried the··more vehemently; nay, at last, began objuring, foaming, imprecating.

It is not particularly common.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the term "abjure".  I may have seen it before, but I do not recall its specific meaning, nor the context in which I saw it.

Here is how I quickly processed this question, and came up with the same answer as Billy ONeal -- despite not being familiar with the word.  Note that the actual meanings of the words are as Billy ONeal looked them up; the guesses below are just approximations.  Approximations are usually good enough to do well on a test like the SAT or GRE:

- The unknown word is a verb.
- All of the proposed opposites are also verbs, so we cannot rule any of them out on part-of-speech grounds.
- Break the unknown word into its parts:  "ab" + "jure".
- "ab-" means "not" or "negate".  (Google defines "[ab-](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:ab)" as meaning "away" or "from", which is a weaker form of "negate".)
- "[-jure](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:jure)" means "having to do with the law", as in "judge", "jury", "jurisprudence", and "jurisdiction".
- Thus, "abjure" might mean "declare not to be the law" or "claim not to be binding".
- "affirm" is a legal term that means "uphold a ruling" or "agree that something is valid".  It is therefore opposite in meaning to the guess.

Here is an optional confirmation:

- Break down "affirm" into its parts:  "ac" + "c->f" + "firm".  (Google breaks it down as ["ad" + "d→f"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:af) + "firm", but the idea is the same.)
- In English, double-consonants near the start of Latin-derived words are usually the result of a multi-letter prefix being modified to match the root word's first letter.  They are usually not the result of a single-letter prefix like "a".
- "ac-" means "with".  (Google defines "[ad-](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:ad%20prefix)" as meaning "toward".)
- "-[firm](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:firm)" means "solid".
- Thus, "affirm" might mean "make solid", which is consistent with "uphold a ruling".